# Viewing paper abstracts from Google Scholar

Tags: google-scholar, online-resource

In a researcher's page in Google Scholar we can click the paper title to see its abstract.

Is it possible to do this from standard Google Scholar search?

(I'm starting to think this is just not possible, but maybe I'm doing something wrong.)

#### No abstract in standard search

[image: no option to view abstract in standard search in Google Scholar]

#### Abstract example as seen from researcher page (by clicking paper title)

[image: paper abstract viewed from researcher page]

---

Update: To clarify, I meant viewing the abstract without leaving Google Scholar. (Microsoft Academic, for example, shows the abstract within the website.)

Comment: maybe there is a greasemonkey browser script to show if the abstract is in the source code of the URL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Scholar's mobile version, clicking on the title of the search result reveals the abstract. In order to show the mobile version on a desktop computer, you have to resort to hacks, such as a mobile browser plugin for your browser or [enabling mobile view](https://askubuntu.com/questions/994739/how-to-force-firefox-to-show-mobile-version-of-websites/994742#994742) in the developer tools of e.g. Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: That does indeed reveal the abstract, but also redirects to the journal's website. I think OP is looking for a way to view Google Scholar's abstract page. (The downvote isn't mine, btw.)

Comment: @Anyon Right, thanks. I tested this one the mobile version. Turns out this might work as a "hack", and I edited this into the answer.

Comment: Anyon's comment is correct. I'm upvoting because the *hack* is useful but I was hoping to get the behavior in the desktop version of the website.